# Make usercontrols and forms inherit from a unique base control

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, inheritance, user-controls

My winform application contains usercontrols and forms.

Each usercontrol inherits a base usercontrol and each form inherits a base form.

The base usercontrol and the base form contain exactly the same properties and methods because what I want is to manage security and language settings at one single place.

This solution is working but I would like all my controls (usercontrols and forms) to inherit a unique base control in order to have these methods at one single place.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Inheriting in this case doesn't make much sense from an OO perspective.

I suggest creating "SecurityManager" and "LanguageManager" classes and using them from your base form & usercontrol. They will have a clear role and let you control the logic from a single place.

Comment: My logic is in a SecurityManager and a LanguageManager, and the BaseForm and BaseUserControl just contain minimal code (acutally one property and one method). Even if it's not much code, it is still duplicated.

Comment: @Anne-Christine, if your properties and methods from your base classes use your manager classes' implementations there shouldn't be any duplicated code.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this issue before.  Unfortunately, since C# doesn't support multiple inheritance, your `BaseForm` and `BaseUserControl` cannot inherit from `BaseFunctions`, and `Form` and `UserControl` (respectively).

The work around I use is to create a `IBaseFunctions` interface with the methods needed and place the functionality in a helper class.

You still have a lot of copy-pasta, but at least it's just the wrapping and not the needed logic.

ex:

```
public interface IBaseFunctions
{
    IUser GetCurrentUser();

    void ShowMessage(String message);
}    

public class BaseFunctionsHelper : IBaseFunctions
{
    public IUser GetCurrentUser()
    {
        // Get Current User
    }

    public void ShowMessage(String message)
    {
        // Show message
    }
}

public class BaseForm : Form, IBaseFunctions
{
    private readonly IBaseFunctions _helper = new BaseFunctionsHelper();

    public IUser GetCurrentUser()
    {
        return _helper.GetCurrentUser();
    }

    public void ShowMessage(String message)
    {
        return _helper.ShowMessage(message);
    }
}

public class BaseControl : UserControl, IBaseFunctions
{
    private readonly IBaseFunctions _helper = new BaseFunctionsHelper();

    public IUser GetCurrentUser()
    {
        return _helper.GetCurrentUser();
    }

    public void ShowMessage(String message)
    {
        return _helper.ShowMessage(message);
    }
}
```